# How can I do voice isolation in Ableton?

Tags: voice, ableton-live

How can I isolate voice from background music? Is it even possible? I tried it with Audacity but the quality is not good enough.

Comment: Ahhh… once more the holy grail of the misinformed. It cannot be done, unless you can afford something like Izotope RX7, a mere 400 dollars.